# Increasing value after changing a references does not increase both values

Tags: c++, reference

When changing the target of a reference in c++, and increasing the initial value, why are `a` and `b` not the same in the following example:

Output: a = 11 / b = 10

```
using namespace std;

void SampleMethod(int& val)
{
    val++;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;

    int& ref = a;
    ref = b;

    SampleMethod(a);


    cout << "Result: " << endl << a << endl << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a working example: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/FVGKtQr

Comment: `ref = b;` just assigns the value from `b`, and not a new reference. Reference variables can only be initialized at declaration. I have no idea, why you would expect that the reference variable should somehow interconnect `a` and `b` magically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void SampleMethod(int& val)
{
    val++;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;

    int& ref = a; //ref bound to a and has a's value i.e. 5
    ref = b; // ref doesn't point to b now but just sets the value of a to 10

    SampleMethod(a); // a gets incremented inside the function and becomes 11


    cout << "Result: " << endl << a << endl << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The reference doesn't track `b`, so `b` doesn't change it's value to 11. It's similar to something like:

```
int* ref = &a;
*ref = b;
```

One probable way to *mitigate* this possible confusion that references could be set to track another variable after being initialized (they can't!) is to use braced initializers for initializing references. So

```
int& ref{a}; //Initializes reference and binds it to a
ref = b; // Changes the value of the underlying object (a) not setting it to b
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I missed the part, that the "alias" is not re-assinged. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> changing the target of a reference

No, references can't be rebound after initialization. Then

```
int& ref = a;     // bind ref to a, i.e. make ref an alias of a
ref = b;          // assign b to ref, as the effect the object bound by ref (i.e. a) is assigned from b with value 10

SampleMethod(a);  // a is incremented to 11, b is still 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I missed the part, that the "alias" is not re-assinged. Thanks!